# What will the $row return in this

Tags: php, mysqli

```
$sql = "SELECT * from bloginfo ";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
```

I want know the value returned by $row

Comment: associative array of you DB table `bloginfo `

Comment: `print_r($row)` or `var_dump($row)`

Comment: @Devsi Odedra can i split that array

Comment: What do you mean by spliting an array?

Comment: can i retrieve the value like $row[1] or $row[3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql = "SELECT * from bloginfo";
```

This will return an associative array of all records from the table bloginfo, if you want to see array that which records are fetching, you can use `print_r($row);` or `var_dump($row);` and if you want to display the record in a table or div then you can do this with foreach loop

```
foreach($row as $value){
  echo "Blog Description: $value['blog_description']<br>";

}
```

blog_description is you field record name to diaplay from bloginfo

Comment: good answer appreciated

Answer (score 0):

For use result, you can use this example:

```
$value= $row['NAMEOFROWDB'];
echo $value;
```

For example if in bloginfo do you have a row with name 'Category' you will use `$row['category']`

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $value= $row['NAMEOFROWDB'];
    echo $value;
}
```

Comment: you are printing only one value right.

Comment: Yes, the value of row you will write. Edited with while.